# How to setup and run Android CTS in Windows OS

Tags: android, cts, android-cts

I want to setup Android CTS in my Windows OS. I didn't found proper links or references to download & install [Android CTS](https://source.android.com/docs/compatibility/cts) for Windows OS.

[Official document](https://source.android.com/docs/compatibility/cts/setup) and few more links are provided for Linux OS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given that the documentation link states `Caution: CTS supports 64-bit Linux machines. CTS is not supported on Windows OS or MacOS.` and has a recommendation of `CTS host machine RAM to 128GB and HDD to 256GB` I'm not sure what you are asking. If you have a machine with enough RAM you might be able to run it under WSL2 but personally I would try to be familiar with running on Linux before attempting in a WSL2 environment.

Answer (score 1):

Official [`Android Compatibility Test Suite (CTS)`](https://source.android.com/docs/compatibility/cts) is primarily designed for and officially supported on Linux and not directly available for Windows.
Here are your options given the above constraint :

1. Live Linux Distribution. Create a bootable Live Linux USB  (e.g. [Linux Lite or Lubuntu](https://www.blackdown.org/best-lightweight-linux-distros/) ) using any of the USB creator tools like [Rufus , Unetbootin](https://techviral.net/bootable-usb-tools-for-windows-linux-macos/)  and then install  Android CTS  .
2. If you insist only windows (  not sure  what sense forces you to ) use `virtualization` software like `VMware` to install Linux on `Virtual Machine` and then CTS. Make sure you have enough Memory and HDD Space to do this.

the official documentation and support for CTS are geared towards Linux.